# Inline width not working in IE when bound with AngularJS

Tags: css, angularjs, internet-explorer

I created a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/14854/) to illustrate the problem.

If I have the following HTML:

```
<div id="div1">
    <div id="div2">Test</div>
    <div id="div3" style="width:{{progress}}%;"></div>  
</div>
```

where eg. `$scope.progress = 50;`, it displays the width properly in FF and Chrome, but in IE, the width is always 100%;

Comment: Would you like to use `<progress value="{{progress}}" max="100"></progress> ` instead? HTML5 only though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use ng-style:

```
<div id="div3" ng-style="{'width': progress + '%' }"></div>
```

Comment: You can read more about that in this issue: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/2186